# Can local storage be maliciously edited client-side?

Tags: security, local-storage

Is a user able to edit localstorage (and sessionstorage) items? Specifically, would a malicious user be able to edit it like cookies can be edited?

I am researching session info for a web application I am writing, and I had the idea of using localstorage for some items. Yes, I have looked into session variables, and I am probably going to use them, but I was just wondering this and could not find it anywhere. My project is built with jQuery and PHP. The interface is completely driven by jQuery, and I am using localstorage for some other info--that is why I thought of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes he can, actually you should always assume that anything that is done on client side 
can be altered, of course JavaScript as well.

If you want to make sure that something is not altered you can use some kind of cryptographic
signature on data and validate it on server side.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to store important information on the client side, so I will just use session variables for the things I want. Thank you Artyom.